Wildcards in vba array
I have this script that moves emails by subject.
How could I use wildcards in the array ?
So in instead of
"Automatic Scheduled Task from FOO : FOO_REPORT/Check trade entry into trade table in last 10 mins", 
 "[PROD] v12.11.102.99 ErrorCheckValidationTransform: 7 Errors for DataTeam_PVCheck_Misc.txt"

maybe just use
"Automatic Scheduled Task from FOO *" and 
"[PROD] v12.11.102.99 *"

script is here
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test")
    Dim varSearchTerm As Variant: For Each varSearchTerm In Array("Automatic Scheduled Task from FOO : FOO_REPORT/Check trade entry into trade table in last 10 mins", "[PROD] v12.11.102.99 ErrorCheckValidationTransform: 7 Errors for DataTeam_PVCheck_Misc.txt")
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[Subject] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
            myItem.Move myDestFolder
            Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend
    Next

End Sub

Its likely you'll need to use either a Left$  or like statement.

Why would you create a script when you can create inbox rules right inside Outlook that automatically run when an email comes in?

My inbox rules have run out.

Dim varSearchTerm as String
Perhaps shorten the first string search in the subject as indicated with a *wildcard. (is an attachment in the subject?) And concate the end string in the varSearchTerm with a wildcard either side of this one. No 2nd wildcard needed if all total strings end the same way.
Regarding wildcard concated around a string in a generic formula as in your example
"" & varSearchTerm & ""
Is a technique in standalone Excel formulas. Wildcard stars are omitted from inside the two sets of speech marks when posted.

You may search for partial text with .Restrict.
Option Explicit

Sub MoveItems()

    Dim myInbox As Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Folder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    
    Dim myRestrictedItems As Items
    
    Set myInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test")
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Array("Automatic Scheduled Task from FOO", "[PROD] v12.11.102.99")
    
    Dim varSearchTerm As Variant
    Dim strFilter As String
    
    For Each varSearchTerm In myArray
    
        strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & _
          " LIKE '%" & varSearchTerm & "%'"
        Debug.Print strFilter
        
        Set myRestrictedItems = myItems.Restrict(strFilter)
        
        Dim i As Long
        Debug.Print "myRestrictedItems.Count: " & myRestrictedItems.count
                
        ' Move or delete in reverse
        For i = myRestrictedItems.count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print "myRestrictedItems(i).subject: " & myRestrictedItems(i).Subject
            myRestrictedItems(i).Move myDestFolder
        Next
        
    Next
    
End Sub

